# How to handle exact decimal values in Go when there is no type that supports it

Tags: math, go, decimal

Go doesn't have a Decimal type, and since floats should never be used to store or perform any math on exact base10 values, how do you accurately work with decimal/exact values in Go? It seems incredibly trivial. I'm not referring to just money/currency values, it could be any exact base10 value with many decimals. I can't imagine that nobody is using Go for monetary calculations, so how are they doing it?

Comment: That appears to be related to storing and converting really big integer values. I'm referring to decimal numbers, exact precision values e.g. 1.23456

Comment: Using ie [github.com/shopspring/decimal](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal)

Comment: Why not https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/?

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging around and see that there are two schools, one is advocating to use Int as representation. Basically the idea is to convert it to counting cents (assuming you are dealing with USD). Eg.:

`23.34` -> `2334`

Another school suggests to use arbitrary-precised representation. Basically `Decimal`module in Python and `BigDecimal` package in Java. In Golang, there is no standard library support on this, but there are third-party libraries like [github.com/shopspring/decimal](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/shopspring/decimal).

There is currently an open proposal on this, but is still on-going. See [proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19787).